# auth.currentUser is showing null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to show logout button when the user is logged in for that i am using auth.currentUser to check if the user is authenticated or not but each and everytime auth.currrentUser is showing null value.
Here is the Navbar where i am using it.

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from '../firebase';

{auth.currentUser ?
                        <>
                            <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/profile">Profile</Link>
                            <Link className="btn btn-primary">Logout</Link>
                        </>
                        :
                        <>
                            <Link className="btn btn-primary mx-2" to="/register">Register</Link>
                            <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/login">Login</Link>
                        </>
                    }
```

This is the firebase config from where auth is comming

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth';  // getting auhtentication from firebase
import {getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_ID,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ID
};


// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);  // now we will export this to use for authentication
const db = getFirestore(app);


export {auth, db};
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication automatically stores the user credentials in most browsers and restores them when the page/app reloads. But this requires that it makes a call to the server (to check for example if the account was disabled), which takes time. By the time your code checks `currentUser` the call to the server hasn't completed yet, and thus `currentUser` is `null`.

To fix this, you'll want to use a so-called auth state listener to get notified and respond to any changes in authentication state. As the first snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) shows:

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```